# batch unrar on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, shell, automator

Here is my shell script I have added to a Automator workflow

```
export VAR=$@
export DIR=${VAR%/*}
/usr/local/bin/unrar x -y "${VAR}" "${DIR}"
```

Input is files and folders in Finder.app. I would like to be able to expand on this and be able to do variations of this. One is to extract to a subfolder in $DIR, named with the archive name (no extension).

My master plan is to have the shell script use the unrar command to 
-extract an .iso in the archives
-mount the .iso
-copy the contents of the mounted .iso to $DIR
-(hdiutil eject?) the .iso
-delete $VAR (the archives)

I'm a beginner in shell language and I don't understand the curly braces, etc.

Comment: I should have added to make this batch if I could either select multiple .rar files all at once as my input, or have it recursively work through subfolders if I selected a parent folder containing all to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ittarate over all the arguments you get checking if the're folders/files, and then extract each relevant rar to it's folder (after creating it)

I would do it like this (assuming you are using bash shell):

```
arguments="$@"

for i in `echo $arguments` #going over the arguments
do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then #checks if its a directory
       folder=`echo $i | sed 's/\/$//'` #to verify that dir's name is not ending with "/"
       archives=`ls "$folder/*.rar"`

       for archive in `echo $archives` #will work also if the folder contains only one rar 
       do 
         final_dir="${folder}/${archive%.rar}"
         mkdir $final_dir
         /usr/local/bin/unrar x -y $archive $final_dir
       done

   elif [ -f "$i" ]; then # checks if it's a regular file
      final_dir="${folder}/${archive%.rar}"
      mkdir $final_dir
      /usr/local/bin/unrar x -y $archive $final_di
   else #error for if the argument is not a dir nor a regular file
      echo "$i is an invaild argument"
   fi

done
```